# I am trying to design a low voltage battery detector .Can someone explain my issue?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Can someone please explain me why the LED is ON for supply voltage greater than equal to 3.5 and LED is off below this point. [image]Rather the opposite should happen -ON below 3.5 and OFF for voltage greater than equal to 3.5..

Comment: A 741 op-amp will not work on a supply voltage below 10 volts; you have it on a 3.5 volt supply. Forget about using a 741. I suggest you also [take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand the motivation that people have for answering questions and things that I mentioned in your earlier post. Also please read this: [Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp).

Comment: *I am trying to design* no you're not designing, you're just "slapping something together" without understanding how it is supposed to work. That's not "designing". Designing means first checking if the components you're using are up to the job. Like the supply voltage of 3.5 V in combination with a 741 opamp. The datasheet of the 741 clearly lists what is needs as a supply voltage. A designer would notice, hey the recommended supply voltage is +/- 10 V (20 V total!!) as a **minimum**. 3.5 V is **waaaaay** less so that's never going to work. So stop calling this "designing", it is not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm guilty of the same occasionally, but: Don't forget to be nice to the newbs!

Answer (score 3):

> Rather the opposite should happen -ON below 3.5 and OFF for voltage greater than equal to 3.5..

That's not true!

Let's model the voltage across D2 to be constant (that's not actually true... but this what the intention of this is).

Then, the higher V_Bat, the higher the voltage across R2 (namely V_Bat/2), and at some point, the input of the non-inverting input of the opamp becomes higher than the voltage of the inverting input.

Then, the output of the opamp becomes high.

Now, you need your opamps output to be low for the LED to light up. So, everything is right here. Current flows through the LED if the output of the opamp is signficantly *lower* than V_Bat!

Also, you're using the 741 opamp. That thing doesn't even work at 3.5 V at all (it's the worst opamp in existence – don't use it).

Comment: I think the 709 was worse than the 741 LOL. And maybe the 702 was even worse LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka :D Though I should probably argue that "in existence" was meant to indicate "exists, can be bought and for some reason is still used"

Comment: Well, [this company](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/T536PE04/UA709+UA709HMQB+High+Performance+Military+Op+Amp+Fairchild.html) are still flogging a dead horse. They say it's sold out but "please check back later" LOL

Answer (score 1):

Switch the inputs to the comparator round and it will work as you expect.

The LED is on if the comparator output is low. As connected if the voltage reference is higher than the measured voltage the comparator output will be low and the LED on.

Comment: I have answered your question if you cant understand my answer then you have no place pulling random rubbish from the internet and posting it here expecting it to be corrected for you (twice now). Make an effort to understand what you are doing. Try doing some research, look up how a comparator works.

Comment: It's a 741 @RoyC and not a comparator AND it won't work on such a low supply voltage.

Comment: @Andy aka I accept that hence random rubbish and marking up Markus's answer.